# print rows where x-numbers of columns are larger than zero

Tags: r

I have a very large data.frame that I want to trim. I want to print only the rows in which more than 50% of the columns have values larger than 0. I have this function that filters all rows that have 0:

```
data <- data[!(apply(data, 1, function(y) any(y == 0))),]
```

my data frame is

```
dim(df.iso)
#1] 30309852       97
```

Where row1=rownames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data[rowMeans(data > 0) > 0.5, ]
```